# Registry Editor - Set Max Idle Time to 14 Days

Tags: windows, hex, decimal, registry, scheduler

I'm trying to set my 'MaxIdleTime' in the Registry Editor.  I have used the following link to set it up to be 5 Days.  How can I make it 14 days?  I want it longer than 5 days, but less the 'Never'  I'm not sure how to convert seconds into Hexadecimal or Decimal value.  Any help would be awesome!

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/118889-remote-desktop-set-time-limit-idle-sessions.html

Thanks,[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was in milliseconds.  I just converted the days I wanted into milliseconds and went from there